# Location: Header redirecting incorrectly

Tags: php

This is just about the last thing I have left to do and I will have officially created my first PHP registration/login system.

What I have is a file called checksession.php. This file checks to see if a user is logged in/has a session created. If the user does, it should let them view their account page. If it isnt, it should send them to index.php.

As it stands, it is sending the user back to index.php even after successfully logging in. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in this script.

**checksession.php**

```
<?php

include('includes/db.php');

session_start();

$userSession = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT emailAddress FROM users WHERE emailAddress='$username' ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$login_user=$row['emailAddress'];

if(!isset($userSession )) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

username is referencing the username field they are filling out when logging in on the login form which is login.php.

On their account page, which in this case is account.php, I have the following:

```
<?php

include("includes/checksession.php");

?>
```

Should this be redirecting to index.php or should it be setting the session based on the username they are inputting? I did make sure the start_session(); on my login.php page as well.

Comment: Are you sure the session variable(s) are being set in login.php?

Comment: Show us the code that is actually creating the $_SESSION['username'] session.

Comment: I have updated my original post

Comment: `$userSession` and `$username` are different variables!

Comment: When you echo out $username, what is there? Do this in the file you're setting $username.

Comment: I get nothing when I add `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` If I just try and echo `$_SESSION` then I get an array to string conversion error.

Comment: Before you access any $_SESSION variable, make sure you have a `session_start();`

Comment: I have `session_start()` at the top of my code.

Comment: @MartyLavender, what I meant was, trying the following:   <?php echo $username; ?> in the file where you're setting the session.

Comment: @AdamA Ahh...I get nothing. Blank when I echo out that variable.

Comment: Are you really getting the user name via a session varible, not via a $_POST variable from a login form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I dont know if this is the best way to do this as I think I may be over complicating this but here we go:

I took the check.php code and actually dropped this into my login code in order to set the SESSION.

Right below that I have the following code:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $login_user; // Initializing Session
            header("location: account.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        } else {...
```

Logged in and voila. I am taken to my account.php like I would expect to be. If I log out and then try to view account.php, I am bounced back over to index.php.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure its session_start(); on my login.php page not start_session();
2. Try to echo out the $userSession and $_SESSION['username'] to see what they actually hold
3. Try the statement this way

.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
     //do what ever
}else{
     header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Variable $userSession will always be set, it may me be null or empty string but it will always be set from your code.

Change the check to:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```